# InvalidUseOfMatchersException when setting expectations in Mockito and Groovy 2.0.4

Tags: exception, groovy, mockito

I am getting an unexpected error when trying to perform a simple test with mocks.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner)
class AccessorTest {

    @Mock
    private DeviceBuilder deviceBuilder

    @Test
    void shouldCreateDeviceFromFilesystem() {
        //given
        URI uri = this.class.classLoader.getResource("sample-filesystem").toURI()
        File deviceRoot = new File(uri)

        Accessor accessor = new Accessor(deviceBuilder)
        Device expectedDevice = new Device(deviceRoot)
        when(deviceBuilder.build(eq(deviceRoot))).thenReturn(expectedDevice)

        //when
        Device device = accessor.readFrom(deviceRoot)
        //then
        assert device == expectedDevice
        verify(deviceBuilder).build(deviceRoot)
    }
}
```

The DeviceBuilder is a single method interface Device::DeviceBuilder#build(File root). Device has a well defined equals method as per Josh Bloch.

The exception is thrown on the when() line, and none of the variables in scope are null. The full exception is:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

For what it's worth here's a snippet of my POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My suspicions are either some weirdness from the way Groovy manages classes, or some version incompatibility, but I hope it's something obvious I just can't see.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. What happens when you do `when(deviceBuilder.build(deviceRoot)).thenReturn(expectedDevice)`?

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't do the basic hello world stubbing on Groovy

Comment: Late answer to myself, the issue I found was because of deviceRoot's metaclass. I solved this by switching the class to Java rather than Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but this may be helpful to someone else.

The issue described in the question is detailed at http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=303

I ran into the very same issue and I got it fixed by using the library provided at https://github.com/cyrusinnovation/mockito-groovy-support

Comment: This isn't quite the answer I ended up with but yes I believe this should also fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Mockito doesn't flag inappropriate uses at the time it occurrs but at the next invocation. You could have a look at the test before that one, maybe you have a problem there?

The message says that in an invocation you either have to provide only Matchers or only real objects, but not a combination thereof. You can usually fix that by using eq(obj) instead of the object itself (or sameInstance(obj)), to have all Matchers. However in this case I don't find any place in the code you posted that would fit that description, that's why I suspect a problem in an earlier place of the code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not answering the original question.

I've searched everywhere and the only question about the error I got points to this discussion.

In case if someone got this error: do not call mock methods to provide values for matchers. The call `deviceBuilder.build` should go BEFORE `verify(`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your answer. The method deviceBuilder.build is being invoked inside the method under test and therefore __is__ before the verify. The other time it is used in the test is because that's the expectation being set